# how to send video and audio streams through sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to build a screen sharing app using **electron js, webRTC , socket io and express**.

Can please explain to me :

how can i send the MediaStream taken from the getDisplayMedia to the server through socket io … I have read articles about that and they explained that it is not possible to send it through websocket however we should use webRTCpeerConnection because the stream is live … Can you tell me more about this and i wonder if i can send video and audio tracks one by one throught web sockets if possible or if you have a solution for that using websocket instead of RTCpeerconnection .
Sorry for the long message, i will appreciate your help <3